# Is it possible for a javascript malware to put keylogger extension in my browser?

Tags: malware, javascript, obfuscation

I clicked on "It's like you" virus in Facebook Messenger. Then I archived the original link with `archive.ph` (`archive.today`), and during the process the site showed me this: `https://pastebin.com/e91wZmqP` (**WARNING! Do not click on any of the links in the paste; they might contain harmful code.**)

The most suspicious js file was the one on the site kiigame. I made an archive, it contains only the text of the script: `https://archive.ph/EAXyP`

The main content of the script seems encrypted(?), as it uses hexadecimal codes for words. Do you know any way **to decipher the hexadecimal codes to see what this script does exactly?** My main concern is if it installed any (hidden) extension (like keylogger) in my browser (I use Google Chrome on Ubuntu).

Comment: The hexadecimal codes aren't encryption nor even encoding; they are simply replacements for human readable function and variable names and, as such, irreversible. However, the structure becomes easier to read with proper indentation. You could use e.g. https://beautifier.io/

Comment: Not possible. Browser prompts to confirm installation of extension and also display its permissions. Also, the extension will remain disabled if it's not available in chrome store.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the source code looks like obfuscated, when I de obfuscate the source it seems like an phisher ? It is asking for FB credentials also has some FB styling and setting/updating some cookies, the best thing what you can do is clean your cache and try malware scan.